# How to get a rectangle around the target object using the features extracted by SIFT in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, sift, object-detection

I'm doing project in OpenCV on object detection which consists of matching the object in template image with the reference image. Using SIFT algorithm the features get acurately detected and matched but I want a rectagle around the matched features
My algorithm uses the KD-Tree est ean First technique to get the matches

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a rectangle around the detected object, [here](http://code.google.com/p/find-object/) you have code example with exactly that. You just need to [draw a rectangle](http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_%28ROI%29) around the homography H.

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Actually I'm using Robb Hess's SIFT library for object matching in my project and the code for match performs as per the requirements but I want a rectangle around the matched object

Comment: Maybe this link helps you better than the other. Drawing a rectangle is relaly easy, just try to understand wgat they are doing and apply to the homography H in your code.
http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_(ROI)

Comment: Thnx Jav_rock the code is very much helpful can i get the documented version of it

Answer (score 5):

I use the following code, adapted from the SURF algoritm in OpenCV (modules/features2d/src/surf.cpp) to extract a surrounding of a keypoint.

Apart from other examples based on rectangles and ROI, this code returns the patch correctly oriented according to the orientation and scale determined by the feature detection algorithm (both available in the `KeyPoint` struct).

An example of the results of the detection on several different images:

[image: SIFT keypoint patch extract example]

```
const int PATCH_SZ = 20;
Mat extractKeyPoint(const Mat& image, KeyPoint kp)
{
    int x = (int)kp.pt.x;
    int y = (int)kp.pt.y;
    float size = kp.size;
    float angle = kp.angle;

    int win_size = (int)((PATCH_SZ+1)*size*1.2f/9.0);
    Mat win(win_size, win_size, CV_8UC3);

    float descriptor_dir = angle * (CV_PI/180);
    float sin_dir = sin(descriptor_dir);
    float cos_dir = cos(descriptor_dir);
    float win_offset = -(float)(win_size-1)/2;
    float start_x = x + win_offset*cos_dir + win_offset*sin_dir;
    float start_y = y - win_offset*sin_dir + win_offset*cos_dir;
    uchar* WIN = win.data;
    uchar* IMG = image.data;
    for( int i = 0; i < win_size; i++, start_x += sin_dir, start_y += cos_dir )
    {
        float pixel_x = start_x;
        float pixel_y = start_y;
        for( int j = 0; j < win_size; j++, pixel_x += cos_dir, pixel_y -= sin_dir )
        {
            int x = std::min(std::max(cvRound(pixel_x), 0), image.cols-1);
            int y = std::min(std::max(cvRound(pixel_y), 0), image.rows-1);
            for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
                WIN[i*win_size*3 + j*3 + c] = IMG[y*image.step1() + x*3 + c];
            }
        }
    }
    return win;
}
```

I am not sure if the scale is entirely OK, but it is taken from the SURF source and the results look relevant to me.